# kendo ui grid edit button not working after loading persisting state

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Teleric kendo UI grid. I am using a database table to store grid options to save (persist) the grid state (column ordering, no of column default viewable etc) . It save option for every user, when the user login agin the state will automatically loded using an ajax call. Everything work fine

But the problem is that Edit button not working after loading saved state. 
Please help.

thanks in advance

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?> 
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">

<div class="panel-body">

<?php
$transport = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransport();

$read = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportRead();

$read->url(site_url('task/jsonMData'))
     ->contentType('application/json')
     ->type('POST');

$transport->read($read)
          ->parameterMap('function(data) {
              return kendo.stringify(data);
          }');

$model = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModel();

$id = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('id');
$id->type('number');

$Name = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('name');
$Name->type('string');

$Address = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('address');
$Address->type('string');



$model->addField($id)
        ->addField($Name)
        ->addField($Address);


$schema = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchema();
$schema->data('data')
       ->model($model)
       ->total('total');

$dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\DataSource();

$dataSource->transport($transport)
           ->pageSize(500)
           ->schema($schema)
           ->serverFiltering(true)
           ->serverSorting(true)
           ->serverGrouping(false)
           ->serverPaging(true);

$grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid('grid');

$idField = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$idField->field('id')
            ->locked(false)
            ->width(60)
            ->hidden(true)
            ->title('ID');


$nameField = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$nameField->field('name')
          ->width(100)
          ->locked(false)
          ->hidden(true)
          ->title('Name');
$addressField = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$addressField->field('address')
          ->width(200)
          ->locked(false)
          ->hidden(true)
          ->title('Address');



$command = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumnCommandItem();
$command->click('commandClick')
        ->text('Edit');

$commandColumn = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$commandColumn->addCommandItem($command)
        ->title('Edit')
        ->width(125);

$excel = new \Kendo\UI\GridExcel();
$excel->fileName(' Task Export.xlsx')
      ->filterable(true)
      ->proxyURL('task/saveToExcel');

$grid->addColumn($id,
$name, $commandColumn)
     ->height(500)
     ->scrollable(true)
     ->editable('popup')
     ->dataSource($dataSource)
     ->resizable(true)
     ->reorderable(true)
     ->sortable(true)
     ->filterable(true)
     ->columnMenu(true)
     ->pageable(true)
     ->addToolbarItem(new \Kendo\UI\GridToolbarItem('excel'))
     ->excel($excel);

$grid->columnHide('function(e) { saveGridState(); }');
$grid->columnShow('function(e) { saveGridState(); }');

 echo $grid->render();
?>

</div></div></div>

<div style="display:none;">
<a href="#" id="hidden-link" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">Click</a>
<input type="hidden" name="rowIndex" id="rowIndex" value="-1" />
<input type="hidden" name="taskId" id="taskId" value="0" />
</div>
<!--to support excel import -->
<script>
function commandClick(e) {


        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        console.log(dataItem);

        var grid = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");
        var row = grid.select();

        var rowIndex = row.index();

        var j = $('#hidden-link');
        if(j)
        {
          $('#rowIndex').val(rowIndex);
          $('#taskId').val(dataItem.id);
          j.attr('href','<?php echo base_url()."task/edit";?>/'+dataItem.id)
          j.click();
        }
    }
</script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        'afterClose':function () {
            var rowIdx = $('#rowIndex').val();
            var taskId = $('#taskId').val();
            if(taskId != 0 && rowIdx >= 0)
            {
                userData = 'id='+taskId;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('task/getTaskById');?>",
                    type: "post",
                    data: userData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        var firstRowItem = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data()[rowIdx];

                        firstRowItem.set('Name',data.name);
                        firstRowItem.set('Plant',data.address);


                    },
                    async:false,
                    error:function(){

                        alert('There is error while submit');
                    }

                });
            }
        },
      });


         var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
         userData = "type='m'";
         $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('task/getGridSavedState');?>",
        type: "post",
                data:{type:'m'},
               // contentType:'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
                    if(data.columns)
                    {
                     options=data;
                     grid.setOptions(options);
                    }
                },
                error:function(){

            console.log("Error loding save grid state");
        }
        });

});
function saveGridState()
{
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    gridOptions=grid.getOptions();
    var request=kendo.stringify({gridOptions : gridOptions,type:'m'});

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('task/saveGridState');?>",
        type: "post",
                contentType:'application/json',
        data: request,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
                    console.log("stated saved");
                },
                error:function(){

            console.log("Error in stated saved")
        }
        });

}

</script>
```

Comment: Code ??? Where is it? We are not psychic you know.

Comment: @David Soussan , I have edited my question and paste the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
     userData = "type='m'";
     $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('task/getGridSavedState');?>",
    type: "post",
            data:{type:'m'},

    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
                if(data.columns)
                {
                 options=data;
                 if(options.editable)
                     {
                        //popout last column i.e command column
                         edit= options.columns.pop()
                         //add new command column explicitly.
                         commandCol={"command":[{"text":"Edit","click":commandClick}],"title":"Edit","width":125};
                         options.columns.push(commandCol);
                         grid.setOptions(options);
                     }
                 }
            },
            error:function(){

        console.log("Error loding save grid state");
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API docs

Notice that when the options object is retrieved and then serialized into a string through JSON.stringify(options), then each field that is a function will be lost. This is limitation of the serialization that the JSON.stringify does. You need to either explicitly set the fields that were functions after parsing the object back or you need to use some custom implementation for serialization to handle the serialization of the JavaScript functions.

So you need to bind the command button to the function again: at least I think that is what they mean. So try adding a basic jQuery ('selector').on('click') function after the setOptions.

Comment: I have try to add a onclick event on the edit button of grid here is the code : `code` $('.k-grid-Edit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            commandClick();
        });  `code`   But it does not work for me

Comment: You have to pass the event in as well you know when you call commandClick(e)

Comment: still not working after passing event e in function commandClick(e) . I have tyr alert() on click. But it also not work.

Comment: Start using Firebug, or similar browser javascript debug to step through the javascript code. You will have to step into the Kendo js so use the full version not the min. This takes time but you will learn a lot. But, if you are using the PHP wrappers then don't you have a commercial licence and support? Either way, try the Kendo forums for help with this.

Comment: I have found the solution i.e first i remove the comand column from columns array and then add a new command column explicitly.   Thank you  "David Soussan " for your valuable help thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm still learning about Kendo UI myself and thanks to you I also leant something usefull here.